# Get a NERDtree'ish list of commonly edited files

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I have between 10-15 files that I edit on a regular basis. I've currently set it up, so I can open them up in a split, by for instance typing: `LEADER + e + v` or `LEADER + e + g` (here are my Vimrc-commands for this):

```
:nnoremap <leader>ev :vsplit $MYVIMRC<cr>   " For my Vimrc-file
:nnoremap <leader>eg :vsplit /path/to/file/foobar.txt<cr>   " Random notes
:nnoremap <leader>et :vsplit /path/to/file/AnotherFile.txt<cr>    " Other stuff
```

The list of files I edit on a regular basis are growing still, - and I use the feature a lot. I was wondering how difficult it would be to make plugin, - where I get a list of files (in a NERDtree-like-view) - where I can pick the file I want to open in a split. I imagined that the list of files would be maintained manually.

The files that I want on this list are in all different kind of folders, so I imagined that the list of files would look something like this:

```
/User/myusername/path/one/random_notes.txt    
/User/myusername/path/two/which/is/different/project_notes.txt 
/User/myusername/path/three/folder/after_work_stuff.txt
```

Is that something that can be achieved without using Vimscript - or which is the best way to make this? Or is it better to make in bash, somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [SPF 13](http://vim.spf13.com/)

If it is more on opening up those files you have been editing, then here's two approaches:

1. In vim, - use the built-in `:browse oldfiles`-command. Then press <kbd>q</kbd>, whereafter you can type a number (listed on the left), followed by <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (to open the file).
2. Use this [vim-session plugin](https://github.com/xolox/vim-session) which is already included in SPF13, then :SaveSession for all the files you are editing, then :OpenSession to edit the files when you are back again. The good part of the Vim-session-plugin is it will keep the documents last save state.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `:browse oldfiles` are really close to what I want. I just wish exactly that, but where the numbers don't change (so I don't have to read the list, in order to find the document I want - but that the documents keep the same numbers). - And I have several of the SPF13-plugins installed already, - but not the `vim-sessions`-plugin. From what I can read, then it doesn't quite suit my need. Option (1) was closer. :-)